# Attribute which wraps functionality of its decorated function within some outer code

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# wrap method via attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206554/c-sharp-wrap-method-via-attributes)

I'd like to achieve such functionality:

```
[Wrap]
public void Foo()
{           
    /* foo logic */
}
```

Where `[Wrap]` attribute is an attribute, which wraps function logic within some outer code - just for example let it be a transaction scope:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    /* foo logic */
    scope.Complete();
}
```

How to write such an attribute ?

Comment: Analogical question I've asked, but with much more detailed answers received is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307298/basic-implementation-of-aop-like-attribute-using-standard-net-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an example of [*aspect oriented programming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) where `Wrap` is an *aspect*.

C# has no built in support for aspect oriented programming, but there are addons such as [postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) that supports it.